# LWJGL/OpenGL - Drawing a maze will only work with square dimensions?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, maze

I've been trying to write some code to generate a maze of any given size (made up of 32x32 tiles), but have run into an odd issue with the rendering code, in that only square mazes will be textured correctly.

I have a single .png file with all possible wall textures, and the floor texture, and dependent on the placement of walls around the currently selected wall during the texturing methods, the correct part of this .png should be selected to make walls blend together nicely. However, as mentioned before, this only works with square mazes (note, rendering is being done with vertex buffer objexts).

Here's the code for generating the maze (currently, it just randomly fills the space with walls, I plan to adjust this part to actually generate a solvable maze once I fix this issue):

```
public void run() { // The maze is part of a thread called World, which runs alongside a Renderer thread
    mazeWidth = 20;
    mazeHeight = 15;
    maze = new byte[mazeWidth][mazeHeight];
}

public static void setUpMaze() {
    for (int x = 0; x < mazeWidth; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < mazeHeight; y++) {
            // TODO Make proper maze generation code
            maze[x][y] = (byte) mazeGenerator.nextInt(2);
        }
    }
}
```

The code to generate the vertices for the triangles to be drawn:

```
private float[] getMazeGrid() { // The 12 comes from the number of coordinates needed to define a square/single tile - 2 triangles, 6 vertices, 2 coordinates per vertex
    float[] mazeGrid = new float[12 * World.mazeWidth * World.mazeHeight];
    int yOffset = 0;
    int xOffset = 0;
        // The if statements adjust the minimum x/y coordinates for each tile, the for iterates through the tiles
        for (int i = 0; i < World.mazeWidth * World.mazeHeight; i++) {
            if (i % World.mazeWidth == 0) {
                xOffset = 0;
            } else {
                xOffset += 32;
            }
            if (i % World.mazeWidth == 0 && i != 0) {
                yOffset += 32;
            }
            // The code below defines one square of the grid
            mazeGrid[12 * i + 0] = xOffset;
            mazeGrid[12 * i + 1] = yOffset;
            mazeGrid[12 * i + 2] = xOffset;
            mazeGrid[12 * i + 3] = yOffset + 32;
            mazeGrid[12 * i + 4] = xOffset + 32;
            mazeGrid[12 * i + 5] = yOffset + 32;
            mazeGrid[12 * i + 6] = xOffset + 32;
            mazeGrid[12 * i + 7] = yOffset + 32;
            mazeGrid[12 * i + 8] = xOffset + 32;
            mazeGrid[12 * i + 9] = yOffset;
            mazeGrid[12 * i + 10] = xOffset;
            mazeGrid[12 * i + 11] = yOffset;                
        }
    return mazeGrid;
}
```

And the code for determining which part of the texture should be used:

```
private float[] getTexCoords(int x, int y) {
    texNumKey = 0;
    if (World.maze[x][y] == 1) {
        if (y > 0) {
            if (World.maze[x][y - 1] == 1) texNumKey += 1;
        }
        if (x > 0) {
            if (World.maze[x - 1][y] == 1) texNumKey += 2;
        }
        if (x < World.mazeWidth - 1) {
            if (World.maze[x + 1][y] == 1) texNumKey += 4;
        }
        if (y < World.mazeHeight - 1) {
            if (World.maze[x][y + 1] == 1) texNumKey += 8;
        }
    } else if (World.maze[x][y] == 0) {
        texNumKey = 16;
    }
    return texMap.get(texNumKey);
}
```

NB: texMap is a HashMap which contains float arrays with texture coordinates to be used by the texture coordinate buffer, keyed with a number from 0-16. The code above iterates through the grid and checks the spaces around the current tile, and selects the correct texture coordinates for that wall type.

Finally, the vertex buffer object code - setting up the VBOs:

```
public void setUp() {
    initialiseTextureMap();

    vertexData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(12 * World.mazeWidth * World.mazeHeight);
    vertexData.put(getMazeGrid());
    vertexData.flip();

    textureData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(12 * World.mazeWidth * World.mazeHeight);
    for (int x = 0; x < World.mazeWidth; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < World.mazeHeight; y++) {
            textureData.put(getTexCoords(x, y));
        }
    }
    textureData.flip();

    vboVertexHandle = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertexHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    vboTextureCoordHandle = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboTextureCoordHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

And drawing the VBOs:

```
public void draw() {            // Draws the entity
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, loadTexture(this.textureKey).getTextureID());

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vboVertexHandle);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vboTextureCoordHandle);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12 * World.mazeWidth * World.mazeHeight);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Most unexplained variable names should be fairly self explanatory, they are defined in the abstract superclass, or in the "Maze" class constructor.

So, for clarity, the above code works perfectly when I set the values of mazeWidth, and mazeHeight to the same value as one another, but if they are different, then textures are not assigned to tiles correctly - here is are examples of the code working, and failing, the top is a 10 x 10 maze, and the bottom 10 x 11: [Maze Examples](http://imgur.com/a/uZ6mb)

EDIT: After switching the x and y for loops in the texture coordinate buffer setup: 
[Maze Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zs6a.jpg)

If you need any other information/I've missed something important out, let me know.

Comment: looking at the pictures looks like width and height are mixed up somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the combination of the for loops for x and y and the push method. You were looping down columns first, rather than across rows first. - the `put` assumes row first looping.

This will fix the problem quickly:

```
for (int y = 0; y < World.mazeHeight; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < World.mazeWidth; x++) {
       textureData.put(getTexCoords(x, y));
    }
}
```

Your texture selection will have to be updated too, mirrored on the diagonal. For example, if you were selecting a texture with the path going South, it will now be drawn with the path going East.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that, however the problem persists, unfortunately. I'll look through and see if anything similar could be happening elsewhere. (also thanks to @BevynQ for the same suggestion)

Comment: Is it a different result though?  Any chance of seeing a screenshot to try to figure out the second bug?

Comment: And now that the loop is changed, your getTexCoords might break for the square version - you may need to update which textures are used - they are probably now rotated.

Comment: Not sure, but it looks somewhat more chaotic than before haha. Of course, I've added one now.

Comment: Ah, ok, I'll check that now.

Comment: Yeah, that was the only issue, everything was rotated randomly, I'm updating the texIDs now to fix the problem. Thanks a lot for your help - though I am confused as to why the getTexCoords method was affected, can you explain?

Comment: For example, imagine a tile on the top edge, with a path going south 1 square.  The messed up loop would draw rows as columns, and the tile would end up on the left edge, with a path going East.  When you picked the textures, you picked the "PathEast" texture as it looked right, but it should have been a "PathSouth" all along.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. You probably saved me a lot of time, would never have spotted the issue myself since it was fairly subtle :)

Answer (score 0):

in setup

try changing

```
for (int x = 0; x < World.mazeWidth; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < World.mazeHeight; y++) {
        textureData.put(getTexCoords(x, y));
    }
}
```

to

```
for (int y = 0; y < World.mazeHeight; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < World.mazeWidth; x++) {
        textureData.put(getTexCoords(x, y));
    }
}
```